# How does bash work on different operating systems?

Tags: bash

How can the bash shell work in many different systems like "**gnu/linux**" "**unix**" and "**freebsd**" etc.? Since the kernels of these systems are different, how can bash perform common functions? For example, the creation and management of processes depends on the mechanisms of the system it is running on. according to the structure of the structure can accommodate many differences. So how can bash communicate with different types of kernels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because they all support the same core API defined by POSIX.  Things like opening files ( open() ) and creating processes ( fork() ) are the same on each of those kernels.